# Oracle sql question, Duplicated days in range- with analytic function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have example table

| Task# | Doctor | FromDay | ToDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bar | 3 | 7 |
| 1 | Bar | 6 | 8 |
| 2 | Bar | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | Bar | 2 | 9 |
| 3 | Bar | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Bar | 6 | 7 |

I need represent only the duplicated days in range

It means that for task 1 Doctor Bar, days 6 and 7
And for task 2 - days 2 and 3. task 3 doesn't have duplicates.

In  different rows:

| Task# | Doctor | Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bar | 6 |
| 1 | Bar | 7 |
| 2 | Bar | 2 |
| 2 | Bar | 3 |

I think some kind of analytic function needed, but not sure.
I hope it is clear enough

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data actually looks like that, you can generate all possible days and join your table to it using a `BETWEEN` condition. The resulting duplicates will be your answer.

```
WITH all_days AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM AS day_number
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= (SELECT MAX(ToDay) FROM tasks)
)
  
SELECT task, doctor, day_number 
FROM all_days
JOIN tasks
ON all_days.day_number BETWEEN tasks.FromDay and tasks.ToDay
GROUP BY task, doctor, day_number
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY task, doctor, day_number
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/paZnX2W9)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
But - whet if I only want tasks that has duplicated days ? 
Let say I have task 3 in other days, But because it doesn't have duplicates I don't want it to appear. 
I will edit the question - so it will be clearer

Comment: This query will do that, it will drop task 3 because of the `HAVING COUNT(1) > 1`. https://dbfiddle.uk/z6G6SYEq

Answer (score 0):

First, identify the overlapping date ranges by performing a self-join on the table with the condition [(StartA <= EndB)  and  (EndA >= StartB)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/4286884) then use the `connect by` clause to extract day ranges :

```
with cte as (
  select t1.Task, t1.Doctor, max(t1.FromDay) as FromDay, min(t1.ToDay) as ToDay
  from mytable t1
  inner join mytable t2 on 
           t1.FromDay <= t2.ToDay and t1.ToDay >= t2.FromDay and
           t1.Task = t2.Task and t1.Doctor = t2.Doctor
  group by t1.Task, t1.Doctor
  having max(t1.FromDay) <= min(t1.ToDay)
)
select Task, Doctor, FromDay + level - 1 AS days
from cte
connect by PRIOR Task = Task
        and PRIOR Doctor = Doctor
        and PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL
        and level <= ToDay - FromDay + 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/PtSRa1JD)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But - whet if I only want tasks that has duplicated days ? Let say I have task 3 in other days, But because it doesn't have duplicates I don't want it to appear. I will edit the question - so it will be clearer

Comment: It is working for this case too, check it here https://dbfiddle.uk/pnB9XAti

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution is to generate required days and use `GROUP BY` to fetch only duplicate days as follows:

```
SELECT t.task, t.doctor, t.FromDay + tt.COLUMN_VALUE - 1 as days
  FROM tasks t
  cross join
       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                            connect by level <= t.today - t.fromday + 1
                           ) as sys.odcinumberlist)) tt
GROUP BY t.task, t.doctor, t.FromDay + tt.COLUMN_VALUE - 1
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY t.task, t.doctor, t.FromDay + tt.COLUMN_VALUE - 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But - whet if I only want tasks that has duplicated days ? Let say I have task 3 in other days, But because it doesn't have duplicates I don't want it to appear. I will edit the question - so it will be clearer